# TYPO3 6.2 / RealURL : 404 error with google tag in URL

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.2.x, realurl

On this website :

https://lessentiel.novethic.fr/blog/business-case-3/post/orpea-dialogue-de-sourds-face-a-lengagement-actionnarial-des-acteurs-de-la-finance-durable-810#scrollTop=0

Google Analytics add parameters for cross-domain-tracking to url so a working link like this one

https://www.novethic.fr/actualite/gouvernance-dentreprise/entreprises-controversees/isr-rse/les-sombres-dessous-d-orpea-ont-echappe-aux-filets-de-la-notation-rse-150534.html

become this, that lead to 404 error

https://www.novethic.fr/actualite/gouvernance-dentreprise/entreprises-controversees/isr-rse/les-sombres-dessous-d-orpea-ont-echappe-aux-filets-de-la-notation-rse-150534.html?_gl=1*1rw78bk*_ga*ODIzMDE2MTIuMTYzODE5MjUyMw..*_ga_FVLX79JNXC*MTY0NDQ4NjM1OC40OC4xLjE2NDQ0ODg2MDkuMA..#_ga=2.179165860.1898940241.1644433835-82301612.1638192523

Any tell TYPO3/ RealURL to ignore cross-domain-tracking parameters ?

_gl=1*1rw78bk*_ga*ODIzMDE2MTIuMTYzODE5MjUyMw..*_ga_FVLX79JNXC*MTY0NDQ4NjM1OC40OC4xLjE2NDQ0ODg2MDkuMA..#_ga=2.179165860.1898940241.1644433835-82301612.1638192523

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look into configuration what is set for the settings:

```
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['FE']['cHashExcludedParameters']
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['FE']['pageNotFoundOnCHashError']
```

In `pageNotFoundOnCHashError` you can define if the system throws a 404 when cHash parameters are not valid e.g. when a parameter was added but not handled in cHash. This is happening when an external service adds parameter like Google does in your case.

In `cHashExcludedParameters` you can define the parameters that are not used to validate the cHash.

There are 2 options now:

1. Set `pageNotFoundOnCHashError` to 0 (not so good solution as there won't be a 404 when someone tries to manipulate the parameters)
2. Add `_gl` to the list of `cHashExcludedParameters` (better solution as you whitelist the Google parameter and keep your system safe)

Comment: Thank's a lot Thomas, it's working perfectly :)
You saved my day !